# What is the correct usage of 'as to'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

I became curious about how to use 'as to.'
I remember I've seen it several times in many sentences, but I cannot be quite sure of its correct usage.
For example, am I using it right when I say
"Would you be so kind as to elaborate on the subject?" ?

Thank you in advance:)

Answer (score 2):

Hello Seige and welcome to English.SE!

I'm not an English teacher, but I personally consider that you can use "as to" in any sentence in which you could use "regarding".

Eg. 1: Would you be so kind **as to** elaborate on the subject?

Eg. 2: Could you please provide more information **regarding** the subject?

Both are polite to say, but "as to" has a different flavor.

Eg. 3: He was uncertain **as to** which road to take.

Eg. 4: He had doubts **regarding** the path he should take.

Though the phrases are different, they provide the same message. Also, "as to" gives you more choices of words and syntax.

Hope this helps!

Robert